# typo3 fe-manager how to get different admin emails

Tags: typo3, user-registration

i have a question about fe-manager. In this extension it is possible to send a confirmation email to a admin. But it is always the same email. i like to send emails to various admins. for example: if the new user is from germany the receiving adress should be some@thing.de. if the new user is from switzerland the adress should be some@thing.ch.
any idea how to approach this?

any hints/solutions are more than welcome.

current state:

extension is created. i copied the finalCreate-Method from the AbstractController to my NewController. i changed the makeEmailArray() from:

`Div::makeEmailArray(
                    $this->settings['new']['notifyAdmin'],
                    $this->settings['new']['email']['createAdminNotify']['receiver']['name']['value']
                ),`

to:

`Div::makeEmailArray('xxx@xxx.ch',
                    $this->settings['new']['email']['createAdminNotify']['receiver']['name']['value']
                ),`

the ts setup.txt file is located in femanager_extended/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.txt
and contains the following code:

`config.tx_extbase.objects {
    In2\Femanager\Controller\NewController.className = Lbaumann\FemanagerExtended\Controller\NewController
}`

is this the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

There is no TypoScriptConfig for this behaiviour, but you can easily override the ControllerMethod and extend it with your needs.

Create your own extension like Vender "Vendor" (company/customername) and key "femanager_extended" with the extension_builder.

femanager_extended/Classes/Controller/NewController.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\FemanagerExtended\Controller;


class NewController extends \In2\Femanager\Controller\NewController
{
    public function finalCreate($user, $action, $redirectByActionName, $login = true)
    {
        // own business logic
        // replace the first Div::makeEmailArray... 
        // with your selected Admin-email-address
        // see parent::finalCreate($user, $action, $redirectByActionName, $login);
    }
}
```

femanager_extened/ext_typoscript_setup.txt

```
config.tx_extbase.objects {
    In2\Femanager\Controller\NewController.className = Vendor\FemanagerExtended\Controller\NewController
}
```

I hope this will help you and i don´t forgot any settings.

Comment: im not sure if this is the right function. i want different cofirmation-email. but it seems the function you mentioned is the one for admin notification. or am i wrong?